# Angular - ag-grid update 'rowdata'

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have the following grid in angular:

[calendar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTkvU.jpg)

If I edit the date in the red box it should affect all the values in the green boxes.  I am not sure how best to do this, can you advise?

My initial thoughts are to trigger a function on edit that gets a cell reference from the item I have changed and update this in the rowdata array and corresponding items.  Effectively refreshing all the data in the 'rowdata' used by the grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no data relation between cells- you have to create it on your own.

As an example - in your data store you would have `start` and `end` dates, other values - would be created based on it.

You can achieve that via [ValuesSetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-setters/#example-value-setter) and [ValueGetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-getters/#top)

[<kbd>Example</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/22NKsxXyTHCz9LBT)

*Total columns - are created based on other cell values - via additional functions*.

So in your case it would be like:

```
colDef: [
    { field: 'startDate'},
    { field: 'endDate'},
    {
      headerName: 'Days',
      valueGetter: (params:any) => getDiffValueGetter(params),
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Weeks',
      valueGetter: (params:any) => getDiffValueGetter(params, true),
    },
]

const oneDayTime = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const oneWeekTime = oneDayTime * 7;

getDiffValueGetter(params: any, isWeekDiff: boolean): number {
    const startDate = new Date(params.getValue('startDate')); //like value "06/30/2019";
    const endDate = new Date(params.getValue('endDate')); // "06/30/2020";

    //don't forget to get a Date object from value
    //so will show just an example of how could it be

    // To calculate the time difference of two dates
    const timeDiff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

   // To calculate the no. of days/weeks between two dates
   return return parseInt(timeDiff / (isWeekDiff ? oneWeekTime : oneDayTime));
}
```

[<kbd>Working demo</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/NQvNhmCyFk1WNAbZ)

**P.S.* it will work with data update - once data is updated - `ValueGetter` would be triggered and update data as needed.*

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I never got around to using AG-Grid in my app but I am sure your answer is correct. Thanks